# Why is cafe pronounced "kisa" in Kobayashi's Dragon Maid?

Tags: japanese-language, miss-kobayashis-dragon-maid

In the first episode of Kobayashi's Dragon maid, Tohru joins a maid cafe. But, in Japanese, Tohru refers to maid cafe as "*maido kisa*". How does cafe become "kisa" if I consider Katakanization of the word? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, found the answer*. I was definitely missing something. She was referring to "[Kissaten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissaten?oldid=477172089)(喫茶店)" or in this case "Meido kissa(メイド喫茶)".

> **A kissaten (喫茶店) is a Japanese-style coffee shop.** Kissaten are particularly popular among students and business people, particularly salarymen, for breakfast.
>
> Kissaten are able to serve sweets and tea, but almost all will also serve coffee, sandwiches, spaghetti, and other light refreshments, as well as curry rice or set meals at lunchtime. In urban areas salarymen and students frequent kissaten for breakfast where they might have "morning service" (mooningu saabisu) of thick toast, boiled or fried eggs, a piece of ham or bacon, and a cup of coffee.
>
> **In Japan, there is a distinct difference between cafes (kaafe) and kissaten. The design and atmosphere of kaafe is usually aimed at younger people or women, whereas kissaten are small, older establishments.**
>
> There is also the very modern phenomenon of the manga kissa, which is a version of the kissaten but with video games, manga and vending machines instead of coffee.

<sub>*I totally forgot I had [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/) bookmarked</sub>